# Hide and Show a table row depending on the row number

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html-table

I am working on a project of mine where I have two tables. The first table contains **companies** and the second the **services** each company has. I would like to implement a new feature. When I click at a row in the companies table, I would like to get the ID and display in the second table with the services only those rows associated with that specific ID.

I have already found how to get the id from the first table. I am now against some code which I am not so familiar.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#firsttable').find('tr').click( function(){
        var row = $(this).find('td:first').text();
        alert('You clicked ' + row);
        //$('#test').toggle('slow');
        var $rowsNo = $('#test tbody tr').filter(function () {
            return $.trim($(this).find('td').eq(1).text()) === row;
        }).toggle();
    });
});
```

My first table has `id="firsttable"` and the second `id="test"`. This row

```
alert('You clicked ' + row);
```

outputs successfully the id. Now what I am trying to do with this part of the code

```
var $rowsNo = $('#test tbody tr').filter(function () {
        return $.trim($(this).find('td').eq(1).text()) === row;
}).toggle();
```

is to hide every row in the table with `id="test"` (services) that has in the second column value equal to the row variable. For example, if the row is 2 I need to hide all rows from the services table that have in the second col value equal to 2. Waiting for tips.

Comment: ok first check the filter change row variable to something like `'2'` if it works you may need to `$.trim` row as well

Comment: After some checks, I found that I need to convert to int both parts of equation using parseInt() function. Now it works. However I dont want multiple selections. I need to automatically hide everything when something is selected. :/ Any ideas?

Comment: @Anonymous - you should post a separate question that includes a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your inquiry on how to `automatically hide everything when something is selected`.